# Unidentified Network on Hyper V External Switch

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, virtual-machines, hyper-v, vswitch

I'm trying to install Windows Server 2012 R2 DataCenter on Hyper-V Windows 8.1.

I've enabled Hyper-V Virtualization from BIOS/UEFI and installed Server 2012 R2 with no issues at all. But now when I want to install AD DS on server I need to assign the static IP to my network switch within the Hyper-V. After applying the static IP address however I'm getting "Unidentified network" error.

I've setup my Virtual Switch (MyVSwitch WLAN) on Hyper-V with settings that are for External Switch by default. The switch is bridged over my WiFi adapter.

I've tried applying static IP addresses to both MyVSwitch WLAN and in the Hyper-V environment with 192.168.1.100 and 192.168.1.101 respectively.

I can't ping any of these two from either side. I've Default Gateway set to 192.168.1.1 in Hyper-V environment. Automatic IP Assigning isn't helping either.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

First off all , the case is  a server 2012R2 VM running on windows 8.1 .

> > *But now when I want to install AD DS on server I need to assign the static IP to my **network switch** within the Hyper-V*.

You need to apply static IP in VM 2012R2 server OS , not 'network switch' .

If the following items are true , you will get a **VNIC** with name 'vEthernet (MyVSwitch WLAN) in win8.1 'network connections' :

1. external Virtual switch named 'MyVSwitch WLAN'
2. selected 'allow management operating system to share...' during creating external Vswitch .

That **VNIC** is used for win8.1 , you may configure IP address on this **VNIC** .

If you both configured IP for that **VNIC** and server 2012R2 VM (assume they are 192.168.1.100 and 192.168.1.101) .

Then the  you need to confirm is Wireless NIC is connecting to AP successfully .

Last thing , please disable firewall on both side .
Ping again .